# random selection of string in java

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

I am working on a project using jsp and servlets and oracle 10g in access layer. I have created a sequence on a field in my database which gets auto incremented when a record is inserted.
The sequence is stored as a string in database. Now i have to select randomly few of these sequence elements using servlets.

How can i do it?

Comment: This is not a JSP/Servlet problem. You would have exactly the same problem when doing so in a plain vanilla Java class with a `main()` method. Your problem is more in the SQL area. I'd suggest to reformulate your question like as "How do I select *n* random rows using SQL?". Then you just have to execute that SQL using JDBC the usual way. It'll give the same results regardless of where you invoke the JDBC code (normal Java class or a Servlet class).

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search led me to the following query:

```
SELECT column FROM
   ( SELECT column FROM table
     ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum <= 10
```

This will select 10 randow table.column values (in Oracle).

If you need more columns:

```
SELECT * FROM
   ( SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table
     ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum <= 10
```

Just use [JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) to execute this query.